# Replacing null values of a column based on another column's values using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I have narrowed down by accessing rows which have a null value for age.
I want to fill in these null values for ages based the median ages for a types of food.

|  | age | favorite-food |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN |  |
| 35 | NaN | pizza |
| 174 | NaN | curry |
| 176 | NaN | candy |
| ... | NaN | ... |

I am using the following dictionary which maps between food types and median ages:

{'pizza': 12.0, 'curry': 16.0, '...' : ...}

I'm trying to use a .replace to replace all the rows with NaN's for ages with the dictionary and store this in a series, then use this series to fillna my larger dataframe's missing age values. I haven't been able to figure out how to use my dictionary's mapping yet though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily using the `fillna` and `map` methods in `pandas`:

```py
# replace your_dict with dictionary mapping
df['age'] = df['age'].fillna(df['favorite-food'].map(your_dict))
```

This is going to fill all the `nan` values based on dictionary mapping you have. **This can be done directly on the larger dataframe that you have**. No need to filter only the `nan` values.

---

Here is an example based on your data:

```py
# generate the data
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'favorite-food': ['pizza','curry','candy']}, index=[1,35,174])

>> print(df)

     age favorite-food
1    NaN         pizza
35   NaN         curry
174  NaN         candy

>> dictionary = {'pizza': 12.0, 'curry': 16.0, 'candy':10.0}
>> df['age'] = df['age'].fillna(df['favorite-food'].map(dictionary))
>> print(df)

      age favorite-food
1    12.0         pizza
35   16.0         curry
174  10.0         candy
```